# Numpy random array limited by other arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two numpy ndarrays with the same sizes.

```
a = np.random.randn(x,y)
b = np.random.randn(x,y)
```

I want to create a new array, where every element will be a random value between the values of the elements with the same indices in `a` and in `b`. So every element `c[i][j]` should be between `a[i][j]` and `b[i][j]`.
Is there any quicker/simpler/more efficient way than to go through all elements of `c` and assign random values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do this:

```
c=a+(b-a)*d
```

with d = random array with values between 0 and 1 in the same dimensions like a

Answer (score 2):

You could use [numpy.random.uniform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html), from the documentation:

> low : float or array_like of floats, optional
>
> Lower boundary of the output interval. All values generated will be
>   greater than or equal to low. The default value is 0.
>
> high : float or array_like of floats
>
> Upper boundary of the output interval. All values generated will be
>   less than high. The default value is 1.0.

So both `low` and `high` can receive arrays as parameters, for the sake of completeness see the code below:

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np

x, y = 5, 5

a = np.random.randn(x, y)
b = np.random.randn(x, y)

high = np.maximum(a, b)
low = np.minimum(a, b)

c = np.random.uniform(low, high, (x, y))

print((low <= c).all() and (c <= high).all())
```

**Output**

```
True
```

In the example above note the usage of [maximum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) and [minimum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) to build both `high` and `low`.  The last line checks that indeed all values of `c` are between `high` and `low`. You can do it all in one-line, if that is of interest to you:

```
c = np.random.uniform(np.minimum(a, b), np.maximum(a, b), (x, y))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea using `numpy`:

```
a = np.random.randn(2,5)
array([[ 1.56068748, -2.21431346],
       [-0.33707115,  0.93420256]])

b = np.random.randn(2,5)
array([[-0.0522846 ,  0.11635731],
       [-0.57028069, -1.08307492]])

# Create an interleaved array from both a and b 
s = np.vstack((a.ravel(),b.ravel()))

array([[ 1.56068748, -2.21431346, -0.33707115,  0.93420256],
       [-0.0522846 ,  0.11635731, -0.57028069, -1.08307492]])

# Feed it to `np.random.uniform` which takes low and high as inputs 
# and reshape it to match input shape
np.random.uniform(*s).reshape(a.shape)

array([[ 0.14467235, -0.79804187],
       [-0.41495614, -0.19177284]])
```